# How to (best) Deploy a Pure Dart (web scraper) App to Firebase or Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, server

## 1. The Problem

I've written a server to provide data to a website I'm going to later on create as pure UI. It successfully periodically scrapes some websites' APIs to collect data and then saves it to Firebase's Realtime Database.

How do I deploy it to a server? Is there a way of doing this with Firebase's Functions? Do I need a Docker image to deploy it on services like Heroku?

The full server app consists of 3 small Dart packages packages and I would rather not publish them on Github if possible.

## 2. Additional Resources

Some of the resources I've found so far:

1. [Build and Deploy a Container on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#other)

   - [The Dart version](https://github.com/knative/docs/tree/a446321306634cbd43fa72ba432fd992c39e0cec/community/samples/serving/helloworld-dart)
2. [Running Dart on a Docker inside the Google Container Engine](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker/tree/master/hello#running-on-google-container-engine)
3. [Heroku Buildpack for Dart, by igrigorik](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dart)
4. [Additional (kind of old) official Server Resources for Dart](https://dart-lang.github.io/server/)

Comment: So far, the closest I got was [this article](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_docker/tree/master/hello#running-on-google-container-engine) talking about how to upload and run a docker container on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I've found so far is to use a Docker runner.

Currently, I'm using Google Compute Engine (GCE) with a simple Debian VM. The basic gist for making it work is simple:

1. Install Docker on the VM (e.g. with [this tutorial](https://tomroth.com.au/gcp-docker/)).
2. Push your container to Docker Hub (you can also store it on Google's Container Registry).
3. Pull the container from Docker Hub from within the VM (SSH into the VM from Google Cloud Platform) and run it.

I've also tried to use Google Cloud Run (GCR), which runs the container directly, without the need of VMs, but couldn't make it work even after some help from Google's support, I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you of Firebase's free 1:1 support, which can be access from the Firebase Support page at https://firebase.google.com/support